# AngularJS with Babel and Webpack not loading component controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm currently trying to build my first project using AngularJS, Babel, and Webpack.

I've got the bundling process working, and everything seems to be working fine, the HTML of my partial is being loaded with no errors, however the controller doesn't seem to be loaded,

I can see in the bundled code that the controller is being correctly bundled, but I can't see what's stopping it from being executed.

Below is everything I've got so far:

**component**

```
import practiceTemplate from './practice.template.html';
var practiceComponent = {
    angularName: "practiceComponent",
    template: practiceTemplate,
    controller: practiceController,
    controllerAs: "practice"
}
/* @ngInject */
class practiceController {
    constructor($http) {
        this.http = $http;
        this.test = "test";
    }
    $onInit() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log("test");
        this.testGet();
    }
    testGet() {
        this.http.get("https://webhook.site/88ea9ff5-a3f7-4c50-9b81-d732d4389d3c").then(response => { console.log(response); });
    }
}
export default practiceComponent;
```

**template**

```
<article>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <p>{{practice.test}}</p>
</article>
```

**app.js**

```
import practiceComponent from './practice/practice.component';
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module("testModule", [])
    .component("practiceComponent", practiceComponent);
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="testModule">
    <practice-component></practice-component>
</div>
```

**webpack.config**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'main': path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts/src/AngularJS/app.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/Scripts/dist/')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
           {
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    plugins: ["angularjs-annotate"]
                }
               }
           },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts/src/AngularJS'),
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loader: 'style!css!stylus'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            }
        ]
    },
    target: "node"
};
```

Comment: do u forgot code that bootstraps angular? e.g. angular.bootstrap(document, [module.name]);

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I've never had to `angular.bootstrap` to run an AngularJS application, I've updated the code to include index.html, with just the `ng-app` definition and the component directive.